# Equivalent of the query from sql server in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, equivalent

I have query in SQL Server , but i don't know its equivalent in mysql.
sql code is:

```
select username as t ,*from users
```

this code running in sql but this code not run in mysql.
is there way?

Comment: Unless I'm being really silly and missing something obvious, I think that should work fine. Do you get an error message of some sort?

Comment: this code not run in mysql , and my error is:  
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `users` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1'

Comment: @aya Please post the exact query you tried and that error message in your OP.

Comment: Well right away I see you're using a LIMIT clause that you didn't mention the original question - what else isn't mentioned? I agree with @MahmoudGamal, we can't help you unless you give us the exact query you're using.

Comment: @aya Really? The answer you've accepted was the same code as you had posted originally, before editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
select *,username as t from users
```

Comment: but this will display the username twice, once as t and the other as username

Comment: yes , but when user if in username field , i can use this code

Answer (score 2):

You can do either

```
select *, username as t from users
```

or

```
select username as t, users.* from users
```

for some reason in MySQL if you specify specific columns first you have to qualify the *

Comment: thanks , the second code help me when i have big fields and i want username given first field.

Comment: Exactly, as an Oracle developer I use the second type most of the time I do this as I have huge tables. You need to qualify in MySQL and Oracle, but not in MS SQL and PostgreSQL which is why it worked in one and not the other.